# Is it possible to simplify this function without using Python's sum(), min(), or max() functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code functions but I was wondering if there was a way to simplify it without using pythons min or max functions. The function takes a non-empty list, L, of [x,y] pairs, and two goal numbers, and returns tuple (closestXY, XorY) where closestXY is the item from L whose x distance from goal X or whose y distance from goalY is the minimum among all distances, and XorY is 'x' if x distance is minimized and 'y' otherwise.

```
    def q1(L, goalX, goalY):
        closestXY = None
        XorY = None
        minValue = None
        for item in L:
            x = item[0]
            y = item[1]
            if minValue==None:
                closestXY = item
                XorY = 'x'
                if x > goalX:
                    minValue = x - goalX
                else:
                    minValue = goalX - x
            if x > goalX and ((x - goalX) < minValue):
                minValue = (x - goalX)
                closestXY = item
                XorY = 'x'
            if x < goalX and ((goalX-x) < minValue):
                minValue = (goalX - x)
                closestXY = item
                XorY = 'x'
            if y > goalY and ((y - goalY) < minValue):
                minValue = (y - goalY)
                closestXY = item
                XorY = 'y'
            if y < goalY and ((goalY - y) < minValue):
                minValue = (goalX - y)
                closestXY = item
                XorY = 'y'
        return (closestXY,XorY)
```

Comment: What if `x` or `y` is exactly equal to the goal? Your code never handles those cases.

Comment: Instead of treating `< goal` and `> goal` separately, use the `abs()` function: `if abs(x - goalX) < minValue:`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `abs()` function so you don't have to handle the cases where the current coordinate is less than and greater than the goal separately.

Also, initialize the variables from the first element of the list before the loop, rather than checking for `None` in the loop.

```
def q1(L, goalX, goalY):
    closestXY = L[0]
    XorY = 'x'
    minValue = abs(goalX - L[0][0])
    for item in L:
        x, y = item
        if abs(x - goalX) < minValue:
            minValue = abs(x - goalX)
            closestXY = item
            XorY = 'x'
        if abs(y - goalY) < minValue:
            minValue = abs(y - goalY)
            closestXY = item
            XorY = 'y'
    return closestXY, XorY
```